# Does Spark optimize the storage when a nested column is cached

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I read a DataFrame from parquet and I want to cache it after selecting some nested structures.

```
df.select($"a.b.c" as "c").cache()
```

I know that the whole `a` column will be read from the input (Spark 2.5. should solved that : [SPARK-17636](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17636)) but I'm wondering if the storage will be more clever and stored only the result of the selection (so not the whole `a`).

Comment: I am not sure how you can check that, good point. The 2.4 bit is?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only the result of the selection is cached after an action is take.  The select statement returns a dataframe, that is the dataframe that is cached.

Note that in your code caching has not yet occurred because no action is taken.  You would need to perform some action to populate the cache like

```
df.select($"a.b.c" as "c").cache().count()
```